# Docker issues with psql database and init.sql file

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psql

Im trying to create a table for my application to use when I start up the container. The application is a simple web scraper that goes to a site scrapes data puts the data into a psql db then displays the scraped data on a site.

I understand that it only needs to run once on initial creation. So I open docker and with no containers I run `docker-compose up` and then I get the error below:

```
app       | 2022-10-08 19:48:21 [scrapy.utils.signal] ERROR: Error caught on signal handler: <bound method CoreStats.spider_closed of <scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats object at 0x7fc61cc3b2b0>>
app       | Traceback (most recent call last):
app       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 103, in crawl
app       |     yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
app       | psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
app       |     Is the server running on host "postgres" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
app       |     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So then I run `docker-compose down -v`. Then I run `docker-compose up --build` and still the db is not being created. However if I run it then go into the db container and create the db then re run it then it works so I know its just some bug with my setup. Is something wrong with my yaml file or init sql file (posted below).

init.sql file

```
\c docker;

DROP TABLE quotes;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quotes (
    id serial not null, 
    author text not null, 
    quote text not null
    );
```

docker yaml file

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: unless-stopped
    hostname: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./app/db/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      # - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

  # adminer:
  #   image: adminer
  #   restart: always
  #   depends_on:
  #     - postgres
  #   # ports:
  #   #   - "8080:8080"
  #   networks:
  #     - docker

  app:
    container_name: app
    image: app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    build: ./app
```

Comment: What is `\c docker;` in your init.sql? Does your postgres container show any logs/errors? And are you sure that `DROP TABLE quotes;` won't error out if `quotes` doesn't exist already?

Comment: its a psql command to change the connection to a new db. Ive tried removing it and it still doesnt work :/ also tried removing the drop table cmd and got the same result.

Comment: i just deleted docker restarted and reinstalled and it worked, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up -d` and get the error, and wait a little bit, and run `docker-compose up -d` again, does it work?  The "connection refused" error implies the database container exists but isn't fully initialized yet; for example, [Running Django app in docker-compose: connection to postgres db refuses the first time but works afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046601/running-django-app-in-docker-compose-connection-to-postgres-db-refuses-the-firs).

Comment: I tried what you suggested  with the `-d` flag and in still getting the same error. I think its something with the db and the connection but I just need it to be reset not really waiting for it, just losing it, idk

Comment: Ill probably end up using the wait for it script. I was able to get that working with the backend, so now Ill try and get it working with the frontend.